# enablepagemethods in ajaxcontroltoolkit

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, scriptmanager

Hi I'm using in my application  with ASP.NET WebForms and VB.NET (code behind) the ajaxcontroltoolkit so, i need use enable a page method but if I add

```
< asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="True" EnablePageMethods="True" > < /asp:ScriptManager >
```

to the code this mark error:

> You can only add one instance of ScriptManager to the page.

My question is in ajaxcontroltoolkit exist a function equal to `EnablePageMethods` of `ScriptManager`?

Comment: Are you referecing a `MasterPage` in this particular page where you're getting the error? It may likely that the `MasterPage` has a `asp:ScriptManager` already declared.

Answer (score 0):

It may likely that you would have definitely added a `ScriptManager` somewhere else in your .aspx Page or MasterPage or UserControl.

If you have declared a `ScriptManager` on your Master page, then in your content pages you would use a [ScriptManagerProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanagerproxy.aspx). This will act as a proxy to the real ScriptManager on your master page.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398863.aspx) is the MSDN link that describes about `ScriptManagerProxy`

*Only one instance of the ScriptManager control can be added to the page. The page can include the control directly, or indirectly inside a nested component such as a user control, content page for a master page, or nested master page. If a page already contains a ScriptManager control, but a nested or parent component needs additional features of the ScriptManager control, the component can include a ScriptManagerProxy control. For example, the ScriptManagerProxy control enables you to add scripts and services that are specific to nested components.*

- Ensure that you have only one `asp:Scriptmanager` on the
  masterpage.
- If you don't need a `asp:Scriptmanager` in materpage then remove it and declare it in content pages whichever needs it.
- If you have a ScriptManager in masterpage then make sure you also have only one
  `asp:ScriptManagerProxy` on every content page that might require a script manager.